# jqueryvalidate $.post using submitHandler

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate, .post

I'm building a small app using jquery mobile and am using jqueryvalidate http://jqueryvalidation.org/ for the form validation. I managed to get a post working using ajax but as soon as I moved it into submitHandler: function(form) it still "works" but I have to click submit twice for it to work? Please help I'm baffled!

```
//the validation stuff
$().ready(function() {      
// validate new id form
$("#addId").validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element.parent()); // <- make sure the error message appears after parent element (after textbox!)
                        },
        rules: {
            idDesc: "required",
            },
         messages: {
            idDesc: "Please enter a valid description",
                },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $('#submit').click(function()
            {
                              $('#addCustId').popup('close');
                              $.post("Customer_AddNewCustomerId.php", $("#addId").serialize(),  function(response)
                                        {
                                             LoadCustomerIdentificationType();
                                        });
                                    });
                            }
                    }); //end validate
                }); // end function
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally wrong...

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $('#submit').click(function() {  // <-- causing your double-click situation
        ....
        $.post(....);
    });
}
```

[As per the documentation for the `submitHandler` callback function](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/),

> *"Callback for handling the actual submit when the form is valid. Gets the form as the only argument. **Replaces the default submit**. The right place to submit a form via Ajax after it is validated."*

In other words, it only fires when button is clicked on a valid form.  The plugin automatically handles the `click`, so wrapping the function within another `click` handler is pointless and counterproductive.

Just do this...

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    ....
    $.post(....);
    return false;  // not necessary, but it reminds me that the default is blocked
}
```

You can leave out the `return false;` line if you wish.  I always put it in (doesn't hurt anything), as it reminds me that the default `action` on the form is not going to happen.

Comment: Ah I see that makes a lot more sense! Thanks so much, your answer worked perfectly :)